# Rudin Real and Complex Analysis Exercise 19 Chapter 2

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\textbf{Background}$

$\qquad$I have been working on this problem (3rd Edition of Rudin Real and Complex Analysis) off and on for quite a while, mainly because of its very alluring, open-ended nature; I tried for a long time, and failed, to prove the entire theorem without Urysohn's Lemma in the case $X$ compact, since a few steps are possible to prove without it, but indeed proving the entire theorem without Theorem 2.12 (Urysohn's Lemma) isn't something I could accomplish.

$\qquad$In particular, Step I seems impossible to prove without Urysohn's Lemma (Theorem 2.12) and its consequence Theorem 2.13. I tried attacking the proof of Step I from many different angles, tried proving various steps without it, and tried coming up with simple alternatives to Urysohn's Lemma and Theorem 2.13, all to no avail.

$\textbf{My Question}$

$\qquad$It is seemingly impossible to find any information about this problem online, which is a shame because it's a wonderful exercise and offers a great way to test one's understanding of Theorem 2.14, the crown jewel of the first half of the book, if not the entire text.

$\qquad$That being said, does anybody have familiarity with RCA problem 2.19? I have solved it in the sense that I came up with various non-trivial simplifications, but I wonder if anybody has come up with further simplifications that did I. In particular, did anybody come up with a way to simplify the proof of / remove Step I or Urysohn's Lemma in their solution?

$\textbf{Problem Statement}$

Go through the proof of Theorem 2.14 (Riesz Representation Theorem), assuming $X$ to be compact rather than just locally compact, and see what simplifications you can find.

$\textbf{Brief Description of My Solution}$

These are the simplifications I could find:

-The statement of the theorem simplifies in a rather straightforward manner, which I won't list out here. The main takeaways are that $\mu(X)<\infty$, that a set is compact iff it is closed, and that $\mathfrak{M}=\mathfrak{M}_F$; it becomes entirely unnecessary to introduce $\mathfrak{M}$.

-Uniqueness can be proven without Urysohn's Lemma since we are now working in $\mathfrak{M}_F$, which is one of the things that motivated me to try to prove the whole theorem without it.

-Step IV can be proven directly from Step I, using the fact that for any two closed sets $K_1,K_2\subset X$ with $K_1\cap K_2=\varnothing$ there exist open $V_1,V_2\subset X$ with $K_i\subset V_i$ and $V_1\cap V_2=\varnothing$.

-Step II is unneccesary; we only need the conclusion $K\prec f\implies\mu(K)\leq\wedge f$ (for Step X)

-Steps VII, VIII are unnecessary since $\mathfrak{M}=\mathfrak{M}_F$.

-Step X is proven identically as it is in the text, except that we mention the above implication in place of Step II; this is the only part of Step II that is utilized in the proof of Step X given in the text.

The steps not mentioned above are ones which either obviously could not be simplified, or which I could not find simplification for. I retained the definitions of $\mu$ and $\mathfrak{M}_F$ used in the text.